cp: Cannot create regular file '/opt/bitnami/airflow/airflow.cfg': Read-only file system
I am using bitnami helm chart latest for airflow with KubernetesExecutor on EKS. I am facing issues with worker pod as below.
cp: cannot create regular file '/opt/bitnami/airflow/airflow.cfg': Read-only file system in {k8s-executor-init-config} worker pod.
I tried changing the security context of pod, disabled containerSecurityContext and changing the UID and GID
